# Extending data model in xcode?

Tags: database, xcode, core-data

So I added a new attribute to an entity in the xcode data model.
Basically like I would do in MySQL adding a new column to a table. However the results were not as pretty as in MySQL/web dev.

When I run the build it throws up "Can't find model for source store".

What do I need to do (steps?) when adding a new attribute to an existing entity in xcode?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data model and if you have saved data using this model then a .storedata file (xml) is generated for you in the `~/Library/<'application name'>/` directory (for cocoa applications). Once this is done if you change the data model(like adding an entity)  the .storedata file will no longer be compatible with the data model. 
So either you have need different versions of your data model or as a temporary solution you can just go ahead and delete your .storedata file from the directory that I mentioned earlier. But this will remove all the data that you would have saved earlier.